# “Cannot send message without a sender address"

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de reservas para un hostel/hostal, cuando la persona realiza su reserva debo enviarle un mail con la confirmación de su reserva y el número de reserva.

Al hacer la reserva, me salta este error:

> Cannot send message without a sender address

Tevisé mi *.ENV* y `config\mail.php` y no logro identificar mi error.

Así está mi *.ENV*:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=a22df0f53ae2b0
MAIL_PASSWORD=867d88b2254325
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=booking@noreply
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Disparador de mail:

```
Mail::to('mail@yopmail.com')->send(new BookingMessage());
```

seguí este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0ynchA_sBA

Comment: [Revisa si la sección *configuring the server*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#configuring-the-sender) resuelve tu necesidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te esta diciendo es que necesitaba saber quien esta enviando el mensaje, entonces en la carpeta mail/BookingMessage especifica el from.

```
 public function build()
      {
           return $this->from('example@example.com')
                        ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
      }
```

Comment: Gracias bro, me solució el problema del emisor, pero ahora me saltó un error de respuesta y las credenciales está puestas, sabes algo de esto?? utilizo maitrap.io "Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required"

Comment: Lo arreglé, sólo tuve que ejecutar: php artisan config:cache